# How do I simplify multiple contributions?

Tags: civicontribute, contacts, contributions, recurring-contributions

Our client is association which only has organizational members. There are no individual memberships. However, member organizations have related contacts who require annual recertification. I want a contribution page, which works like an event registration, allowing one individual to register multiple contacts at the same time, but for an annual recertification fee. It's not an event and each contact should receive their annual reminder that certification will expire in a year.

I don't see this option for recurring contributions or memberships. Did I miss something or does someone have a clever solution for our unusual situation?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with Webform-CiviCRM integration, and probably with Caldera Form as well.  You can create multiple contats on a single form, specify a single fee, create relationships between the organization and individual.  The annual reminder can be sent out in a number of ways; if you're using Drupal, I'd just use the Webform email functionality to send the email to all the individuals.

Comment: We're in WordPress and it's certainly worth a shot with Caldera.